# Indiegogo CDN is bugged?

Tags: javascript, cdn

I have noticed over the past few weeks that our Indiegogo image has not been visible on our website. We are running the companies official embed code and everything has been working fine for the last six months, but something is seriously bugged on their end, and I wanted confirmation from you fine folk.

Here are the errors coming back from inspecting the image.

```
https://g0.iggcdn.com/javascripts/ancillary.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g3.iggcdn.com/javascripts/dependencies.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g0.iggcdn.com/javascripts/ancillary.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g3.iggcdn.com/javascripts/dependencies.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g0.iggcdn.com/javascripts/ancillary.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g3.iggcdn.com/javascripts/dependencies.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://g0.iggcdn.com/javascripts/ancillary.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You should probably just contact their support.

Comment: I just want to verify this is a problem on their end, and not a problem on our end. I also wanted someone to speculate what the problem on their end might be? I am not a programmer, but it looks like maybe the sub-domains assigned to the CDN might be reconfigured?

Comment: As long as you're using their official code and still getting 404s, the problem is most likely on their end, unless you just have a browser extension interfering or something.

Comment: It looks like they read this post and fixed it.